# How can I select only unordered factors from my data frame?

Tags: r

I cannot find a simple way to select only columns of nominal (unordered factor) variables from a data frame.

I've tried using the expression "!is.ordered" to grab factor variables that are not ordered, but that throws an error.

```
df=mtcars
df$am=as.factor(df$am)
df$carb=as.ordered(df$carb)
df2=df[,lapply(df,(is.factor & !is.ordered))]
```

Error in !is.ordered : invalid argument type

This doesn't work either:

```
df=mtcars
df$am=as.factor(df$am)
df$carb=as.ordered(df$carb)
df2=df[,sapply(df, is.factor)]
ords=unlist(lapply(df2,is.ordered))
df2=df2[,-ords]
names(df2)
```

NULL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df[,sapply(df, function(x) is.factor(x) & !is.ordered(x)), drop = FALSE]

dplyr::select_if(df, ~ !is.ordered(.) & is.factor(.)) # Extended by is.factor of utubun
```

From readability statepoint if would prefer the dplyr function, but it´s always nice to have a `base` R alternative.

Comment: Agreed, `base` must be always present as a solution. +

Answer (score 1):

Try it with `dplyr`:

```
dplyr::select_if(df, ~ !is.ordered(.))
```